# Adding PubNub to Chat Server

Tags: php, xampp, pubnub

I wish to add PubNub to my chat server to allow for real time sending and receiving of messages. At present, the server is built in PHP as a series of `switch-case` actions.

However, simply adding the instantiate and subscription to the top of the server:

```
$pubnub = new Pubnub(
    "key",  ## PUBLISH_KEY
    "key"  ## SUBSCRIBE_KEY
);

// Subscribing to the main server channel

$pubnub->subscribe('MAIN_SERVER', function($message) {
    //var_dump($message);  ## Print Message
    return true;         ## Keep listening (return false to stop)
});

....

switch($action) 
{

    // Complete:
    case "userLogin": 
        //error_log($username,0,"error.log");
        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password, $gcmregid)) 
        {   
            // Then they are a user, so yes, then in app, will call the "syncWithServer" action case
            $out = json_encode(array('response' => SUCCESSFUL));

        }
        else
....
```

causes the server to timeout:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Server\lib\Pubnub\Clients\DefaultClient.php on line 30
```

How can PubNub be integrated into my present server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PHP Subscribe Loop with PubNub

This is a blocking call.  You need to run this method outside of a web-server environment.  Instead you need to run your script in a command line.  Also you will want to monitor this process using `upstart` or similar system level

```
## Process Messages
function receive_and_process($message) {
    switch($messge->action) { ... }
}

## This is BLOCKING
$pubnub->subscribe('MAIN_SERVER', function($message) {
    receive_and_process($message);
    return true;
});
```

Your Start command would be **`php my-php-server.php`**.